# php included navigation menu not working

Tags: php, menu, navigation, include

I have a php page that has many includes. The whole page runs fine,  but for my navigation bar, it does not open any page when I click on it. Please, what is missing here. Any help will be appreciated. many thanks

Here are my codes for the includes

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href="../index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="../About.php"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li><a href="../packages.php"><span>Packages</span></a></li>
<li><a href="../Patners.php"><span>Partners</span></a></li>
<li><a href="../gallery.php"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href="../contactus.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here is my main page code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<img src="images/banner.png" width="940" height="200"  />
</div>
<?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/slider.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/contents.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/sidebar.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div> <!-- End #wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: OK don't open a page but what you got? Page not found error? You must set to an actual page, also, you shouldn't put <span> tag inside in a <a> tag, however it'll works anyway.

Comment: it was not opening up any page at all....something typical of the <a href="#"> behavior. But I managed to get my way around it. Thanks to happypete and Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your file structure, but try removing the '../' on all you links

Change this:

```
<li class='active'><a href="../index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

to this:

```
<li class='active'><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

Comment: thanks a million, this did it, it's working now. Though besides the <a href="index.php">, the directory was not complete...in my case, <a href="phpdemo2/index.php"> did the magic. thank you so much for you response.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ../ out of your path.

When you include the nav.htm to your main page it acts as if it is in the main folder
Therefore if you use '../' it won't find it.

Comment: This also helped in correcting the problem. It was an incomplete directory issue. but it's fixed now. Million thanks again for your feedback.